# How do I make appear no-numbered sections in the hyperlinks (bookmarks) of a PDF?

Tags: sectioning, pdf, bookmarks, starred-version

I am using `\section*{}` to get unnumbered sections in a document. I need to get those sections in the bookmarks of the resulting PDF but they don't show up.
In addition, if the first section is unnumbered, none of the sections below appear either on the PDF.

Comment: Are you also using numbered sections?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Have a look at the `bookmark` package. It allows you to add PDF bookmarks by yourself. Are you using `article` or similar class without a `\chapter` level?

Comment: Related: [No section numbers, but still have PDF bookmarks with hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33696/17427)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `\pdfbookmark` command provided by the `hyperref` package which lets you set bookmarks manually. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\begin{document}

\section{Numbered Section One}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{Numbered Section Two}
\lipsum[1-6]
\pdfbookmark[1]{Unnumbered Section}{unnumbered}
\section*{Unnumbered Section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Numbered Section Three}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `page=2` not simply link to the page 2 without taking `\phantomsection` into account?

Comment: @Martin: fixed. I used `\newpage` and then replace it with `\phantomsection` while doing some tests and forgot to delete `\phantomsection`.

Comment: But this still forces the document author to manually insert the correct page numbers by hand. Also it links to the whole page, not the unnumbered section.

Comment: @Martin: right. Anyway, I've changed my answer. Now I only use `\pdfbookmark` from `hyperref` which, in this case, seems like a better option.