# References in bookmarks

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, bookmarks

The references does not appear in bookmarks. I am using the following environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{someitem}
\end{document}
```

How can I add the References to the bookmarks?

Comment: some related information at [How do I make appear no-numbered sections in the hyperlinks (bookmarks) of a PDF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21688/579)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, by default, unnumbered (or starred) sections do not show up in the bookmarks. And, as you noted, References are unnumbered. Use it as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}% Add references to ToC (and bookmarks)
\bibitem{someitem}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to "[Tame the BeaST - The B to X of BibTEX](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf)" page 4 footnote 3:

> In order to cleanly insert the bibliography in your table of contents, use the `tocbibind.sty` package. Other methods you can think of will probably lead to wrong page numbers.

---

Following practice seems to work again with the help of `\phantomsection`.

> [SDrolet's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325853/34699) to show `Bibliography` of `Reference` on content page might also work here, though we are using `biblatex` and/or `biblatex-chicago` package as well as `hyperref` and/or `bookmark`...
>
> Use the following in your premeable.
>
> ```
> \usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
> \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
> ```
>
> You might want to replace `\jobname` with your `.bib` file name, if it is different from your main `.tex` file.
>
> Then add the following before `\end{document}`.
>
> ```
> \phantomsection
> \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
> ```
>
> This is the first solution I have seen without additional package(s) or potential issues with table of content, i.e. the simplest or cleanest solution to show `Reference` as a top-level section in corresponding pdf bookmark. **[Now seems to work fine again...]**