# Adding a bookmark for references

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I have the following simple code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Hussein Eid}
\begin{document}

\section{Section A}
This is section one 

\section{Section B}
This is section two

\begin{thebibliography}{3}
\bibitem{adnan}
  A. Tercan and C.C. Yucel: \textit{Module Theory, Extending Module and 
  Generalization} (Birkhäuser Basel, Basel, 2016).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I need to add a bookmark for 'references' section in the .pdf file as shown in the picture below:
[image]

How can I achieve this ?! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean here? Clickable where? Section A and B in your example is not clickable. Please be more specific.

Comment: When I run this code and produce a .pdf file, it's supposed that the .pdf file has a table of contents (sections names) on the left. In this table, you can see 'section A' and 'section B' and when you click any of them, you are directed to the head of the section. But this is not the case for 'references'. I ask: how to make 'references' behaves as 'section A' and 'section B' ?!. @daleif

Comment: If you also have a table of contents in your real document then you can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112518/references-in-bookmarks.

Comment: If you only want the pdf bookmarks and not a table of contents then https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/add-pdf-bookmark-manually is applicable I think.

Comment: Your example does not provide and table of contents nor any pdf bookmarks. You're probably looking for the `hyperref` package. As for getting the references into the ToC and into the bookmarks, for your MWE see the `tocbibind` package.

Comment: I edited the question @daleif

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found out an answer:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Section A}
This is section one 

\section{Section B}
This is section two

\begin{thebibliography}{3}
% To add a bookmark for the references in the .pdf file
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}
\bibitem{adnan}
  A. Tercan and C.C. Yucel: \textit{Module Theory, Extending Module and 
  Generalization} (Birkhäuser Basel, Basel, 2016).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```